# Deploying Files to IsolatedStorage in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

Hi everyone 
I would like to know if it's possible to deploy my app assets directly to Isolated Storage once the app get deployed. 
I'm currently extracting them from code but this make the app's first launch too slow and it will be declined once it's submitted to the marketplace. 
I'm wondering if there is a nice trick to make the process faster 
Thanks

Comment: I'm currently embedding them with the app assembly, the assets are a set of photos, video and XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to automatically deploy to IsolatedStorage on app installation.

There are a few things you can do to try and avoid a delay on first start up though:

- Refer to files directly in the XAP where possible.
- Split the assets into multiple dlls so that only those needed are loaded into memory.
- Load content to IS in the background and prioritize this so that the resources are loaded as needed.

You should not need to load image or video files into IS just to view them.
You should only need to copy the XML files if they're going to be updated. If you just want to read some data this doesn't need to be done. Also, if the XML files just hold initial data/state this could be loaded from the assembly directed and only saved to IS when first persisted.